# Google reCAPTCHA "Type the Text"

Tags: php, captcha

I'm currently trying out Google reCAPTCHA and I want the challenges to be "Type the Text" where it will only shows digitized text/numbers and the user will just type what they see on the digitized text/numbers, instead of choosing pictures to solve the challenge. Currently I'm using version 2 of it, but I'm wondering if there is a line of code to add so I can use the challenges like in version 1 or can I still use the version 1 instead of version 2.

Thank you for your help in advance.

***Update***

I tried changing the script 
`<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=<?php echo RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY; ?>'></script>`

and the old version of reCAPTCHA is displaying but when submitting the form it returns

**Captcha is invalid.**

and the recaptcha is not displayed inside my form.

Comment: The idea behind version 2 is to actually be less intrusive - it uses some heuristics around how the user interacts with the page/control to determine if it even needs to show you the puzzle - often it will just show the tick box and let you through. If you change the call to use the v1 reCAPTCHA, you'll also need to ensure that you have [updated the server side code to support that version as well](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/php#client-side-how-to-make-the-captcha-image-show-up).